# Where are the mount points defined in CentOS?

Tags: filesystems, mount

There is a mount point at /mnt/mountname and it goes to a large SAN with lots of storage but it's mounted as a read-only filesystem. I want to add a mount point with a different name that's read-write. I've looked in /etc/fstab and /etc/vfstab (which doesn't exist) and there is nothing there that mentions /mnt/mountname. Where else can I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mount mounts are defined at /etc/fstab however the file system mounted at /mnt/mountname may have been mounted "by hand" or something may have mounted it after the system started. IE, someone may have have just typed the following in the terminal to mount it:

```
mount /dev/foo /mnt/mountname
```

If you want to add /mnt/mountname to /etc/fstab and/or want to use it as a template for the new one you're adding, you can run the following to show you what the line in /etc/fstab should look like:

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

If that doesn't work, try 'cat /proc/mounts'.

Comment: /etc/mtab is it! That's where it's defined. When you use the "mount" command why don't you have to specify the type or if it's ro or rw like what's specified in /etc/mtab?

Comment: @tooshel: `/etc/mtab` doesn't define mount points, it is updated by the `mount` command. It contains the options that `mount` passes to the kernel.

Comment: @tooshel: Regarding you not having to specify the type or ro/rw, mount will try to figure out the fs type on its own if you don't specify one. Likewise if you don't include any options it will default to rw and other options depending on what type the fs is. If you search the mount man page of your distro for 'mtab' and 'defaults' under '-o' it will tell you more.